# AWS DHCP Options Set - Custom DNS Server

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, redhat, domain

I have taken a windows R2 2012 instance on AWS. I have configured Active directory and from other linux instances I am able to do `kinit`. My Windows domain name is `xyz.example.local`

Now from My RHEL instances I want to join this domain for that I fired

```
realm -v join --user=myuser@xyz.example.local xyz.example.local
```

However it didnt work. So, I debug and found that I am not able to use dig or nslookup. I tried

```
nslookup xyz.example.local
```

and It's getting timeout.

I have also tried changing the DHCP option sets in VPC and provided the ipaddress of my windows instance as nameserver. Tried putting same ip in `resolv.conf`. However, no luck.